# How to perfect url in address bar php, .htaccess, or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This my .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    ErrorDocument 404 /?page=404

    # 1-level
    RewriteRule ^contact/{0,1}$  index.php?p=contact [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^displaydata/{0,1}$  index.php?p=displaydata [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^log-in/{0,1}$  index.php?p=log-in [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^log-out/{0,1}$     ?p=log-out [QSA,L]

    # newweb.com/contact# = newweb.com/contact/#
    #RewriteRule ^contact/(.*)?$ $1
    #RewriteRule ^displaydata/(.*)?$ $1
    #RewriteRule ^log-in/(.*)?$ $1
    #RewriteRule ^log-out/(.*)?$ $1


    ####
    # set URI to /index.php/200 if query string is id=200
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(200|1)(?:&|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/?$ $1/%1 [NC]

    # set SECURED var to 1 if URI is /index.php/200
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/index\.php/(200|1)" SECURED

    # enforce auth if SECURED=1
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Login Required"
    AuthUserFile /full/path/to/passwords
    Require valid-user
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=SECURED
    Satisfy any
    #####
    # all other cases
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .+ -  [L]
    </IfModule>
```

And this is Javascript:

```js
 var reg_e=/#$/; if(!window.location.href.match(reg_e)) 
    { 
     window.location.href = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+"#";
    }
```

My url in the address bar :

```
newweb.com
```

added '#':

```
newweb.com/contact#
```

This is really good and works. But! My problem is:

I want this url

```
newweb.com/contact/#
```

to be

```
newweb.com/contact#
```

because the css won't load with the /. So I'd added `RewriteRule ^contact/(.*)?$ $1`

It works for contact/#

but when I click other link I will get:

```
newweb.com/contact/displaydata#
```

instead of :

```
newweb.com/displaydata#
```

How perfect url? Opinions and articles would be really welcome.

Comment: in your `<head>` section set a `<base />` tag.

Comment: Hi. Muntashir Akon.  I'd added it but not working

Comment: Still the same problem?

Comment: Do you have what methods to when someone try to add '/' at final url http://newweb.com/displaydata/# will return http://newweb.com/displaydata# or not change page?

Comment: Not really. In my website I always use `<base href="/">` so that all the link will be absolute to the root. So, whatever user tries to do, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Perhaps,  my directory structure!

Answer (score 2):

Try this may be, might work sometimes. Put this first under your `<head>`:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Or use the `src` and `href` in such a way, that it is relative to the domain.

```
<a href="/some/path/to/file"></a>
<link rel="" href="/some/path/to/file" />
<script src="/some/path/to/file"></script>
<img src="/some/path/to/file" />
```

When you use any URL this way, you will be able to get it:

```
"http://example.com/my/path/#".substr(-2)  // "/#"
```

So keeping this as a thing, you can do:

```
var url = "http://example.com/my/path/#";
if (url.substr(-2) == "/#")
  window.location.href = url.substr(-2) + "#";
```

Comment: css, popup, login, contact, displaydata folder of the same level is child of newweb folder. index.php in newweb folder,

Comment: @TríĐứcĐào Are you using a linux machine? At least, where the server is hosted?

Comment: Im using window. that's localhost:8080

Comment: Do you have what methods to when someone try to add '/' at final url newweb.com/displaydata/# will return newweb.com/displaydata# or not change page?

Comment: @TríĐứcĐào like what? Methods?

Comment: @TríĐứcĐào Got a solution.

Comment: I dont understand buddy ?

Comment: @TríĐứcĐào Just change it to: `var url = location.href;` And see if that works? Add the code to your page.

Comment: @TríĐứcĐào Woah, why? Give the base now. Remove all the unnecessary rewrite rules.

Comment: I think that my problem is at my .htaccess and my directory structure as you said. You right. Must remove

Comment: Of course, testing testing I'm trying to remove .htaccess

Comment: I can't remove it. because page will return "Index of /" folder list in localhost